# TensorFlow softmax_crossentropy_with logits: are "labels" also trained (if differentiable)?

Tags: tensorflow, fixed, label, gradient, loss-function

The softmax cross-entropy with logits loss function is used to reduce the difference between the logits and labels provided to the function. Typically, the labels are fixed for supervised learning and the logits are adapted. But what happens when the labels come from a differentiable source, e.g., another network? Do both networks, i.e., the "logits network" and the "labels network" get trained by the subsequent optimizer, or does this loss function always treat the labels as fixed?

TLDR: Does tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits() also provide gradients for the labels (if they are differentiable), or are they always  considered fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tf.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2 to get gradients with respect to labels.

Answer (score -1):

The gradient is calculated from loss provided to the optimizer, if the "labels" are coming from another trainable network, then yes, these will be modified, since they influence the loss. The correct way of using another networks outputs for your own is to define it as untrainable, or make a list of all variables you want to train and pass them to the optimizer explicitly.